# How to get attribute value in jquery

Tags: html, jquery, xml

I'm trying to get the XML `media:content`'s attribute '`url`' value through jQuery.

My XML example:

```
<item>
 <media:content medium="image" url="https://scontent-atl3-2.cdninstagram.com/v/t51.2885-15/284808980_196032332753770_8611785610950582152_n.jpg?stp=dst-jpg_e35&_nc_ht=scontent-atl3-2.cdninstagram.com&_nc_cat=110&_nc_ohc=SvzFVxnmeFEAX-xgjys&edm=AAuNW_gBAAAA&ccb=7-5&oh=00_AT8vFMpa0kgqFMBkyPMxF8lTVJwI_IRVMalS_3SSTjvvBA&oe=62A141BA&_nc_sid=498da5" width="750" height="750"/>
</item>
<item>
 <media:content medium="image" url="https://scontent-atl3-2.cdninstagram.com/v/t51.2885-15/284659678_579337080184778_276124491395057868_n.jpg?stp=dst-jpg_e35&_nc_ht=scontent-atl3-2.cdninstagram.com&_nc_cat=102&_nc_ohc=K59Gp5usXS4AX9JCj39&edm=AAuNW_gBAAAA&ccb=7-5&oh=00_AT-r4eyj_VGS-3ENiVFEve_DoEaH4QVRAC52aMZJFeWhNA&oe=62A07EDC&_nc_sid=498da5" width="612" height="323"/>
</item>
```

And this is how I'm trying to get.

```
var imgsArr = [];

var $xmlData = $(data)
               .find("item > media:content").attr('url');
               .each(function () {
                imgsArr.push($(this).text());
               })
```

By this I'm getting an error `Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'text')`

I've tried `media\\:content` and `media\\:content, content` as well but still no success.

The reason I'm doing this is because later I have to use this url tag in HTML img tag.

My full code can be found at [CodeSandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/zealous-cori-ec6mo9?file=/src/index.js). As you can see in my CodeSandbox it works great for `item > link` and I'm able to render it on screen as well.

And my [RSS xml feed](https://rss.app/feeds/i0QRdHCkHgYPGNWs.xml)

Please any help would be appreciated.